# extract Embedded initramfs

Tags: linux, kernel, initramfs

I have a kernel in which one initramfs is embedded. 
I want to extract it.

I got the output `x86 boot sector` when I do `file bzImage`

I have System.map file for this kernel image.

Is there any way to extract the embedded initramfs image from this kernel with or without the help of *System.map* file ?

The interesting string found in *System map* file is: (Just in case it helps)

```
57312:c17fd8cc T __initramfs_start
57316:c19d7b90 T __initramfs_size
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is some information about this in the gentoo wiki: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Salvaging

It recommends the usage of `binwalk` which works exceedingly well.

I'll give a quick walk-through with an example:

first extract the bzImage file with binwalk:

```
> binwalk --extract bzImage
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Microsoft executable, portable (PE)
18356         0x47B4          xz compressed data
9772088       0x951C38        xz compressed data
```

I ended up with three files: `47B4`, `47B4.xz` and `951C38.xz`

```
> file 47B4
47B4: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=aa47c6853b19e9242401db60d6ce12fe84814020, stripped
```

Now lets run binwalk again on `47B4`:

```
> binwalk --extract 47B4
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ELF, 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
9818304       0x95D0C0        Linux kernel version "4.4.6-gentoo (root@host) (gcc version 4.9.3 (Gentoo Hardened 4.9.3 p1.5, pie-0.6.4) ) #1 SMP Tue Apr 12 14:55:10 CEST 2016"
9977288       0x983DC8        gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
<snip>
```

This came back with a long list of found paths and several potentially interesting files. Lets have a look.

```
> file _47B4.extracted/*
<snip>
_47B4.extracted/E9B348:     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

file `E9B348` is a (already decompressed) cpio archive, just what we are looking for! Bingo!

To unpack the uncompressed cpio archive (your initramfs!) in your current directory just run

```
> cpio -i < E9B348
```

That was almost too easy. `binwalk` is absolutely the tool you are looking for. For reference, I was using v2.1.1 here.

Comment: Bingo !!! You nailed it !

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the initramfs cpio archive is just linked into the kernel.

Hence, this should work:

1. use `dd` to extract the range between `c17fd8cc` and `c19d7b90`
2. unpack the resulting data ny using an CPIO unpacker.

Answer (score 0):

Using "dd to extract the range between c17fd8cc and c19d7b90" is not going to work, because those are kernel virtual addresses, and your image is in physical space. You would need to translate them into image offsets in order for this to work. Generally, subtract the virtual offset (in this case, looks like 0xC0000000) and possibly add PHYS_OFFSET (usually 0x8000) but that depends on your kernel.