# How to combine linux kernel and initrd without compiling?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, initramfs, initrd

I know that it's possible to [extract from a linux kernel the embedded initramfs cpio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286800/147473). I want to know if the reverse operation is possible; i.e., given both a compiled kernel and initramfs archive, how does one combine them?

I'm trying to achieve the same effect of this kernel config...

```shell
CONFIG_EFI=y
CONFIG_EFI_STUB=y
...
CONFIG_FB_EFI=y
...
CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE="root=..."
...
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE="my_initrd.cpio"
```

...without actually configuring and/or compiling the kernel.

References:

- http://www.kroah.com/log/blog/2013/09/02/booting-a-self-signed-linux-kernel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution:
you can create a combined `.efi` image
with kernel, command line and initramfs inside,
called a "unified kernel image".

Reference: [Preparing a unified kernel image – ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_kernel_image#Preparing_a_unified_kernel_image). 
You might want to focus on the [“Manually”](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_kernel_image#Manually) subsection.

Comment: That's the answer I've been waiting for; excellent find, @user429255